# Mock object throws NPE

Tags: spring, mockito

i going to create mockito test for my service layer, I give an example one of class this layer below

```
 @Service
public class LangServiceImpl implements LangService {
    @Autowired
    private LangDaoImpl langDao;

    public LangDaoImpl getLangDao() {
        return langDao;
    }

    public void setLangDao(LangDaoImpl langDao) {
        this.langDao = langDao;
    }

    ...
}
```

When i was running my test, i got this NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.phonebook.service.LangServiceTest.getByIdTest(LangServiceTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

I wrote this test

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class LangServiceTest {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AddressDao.class);
        private final String COUNTRY_NAME = "Ukraine";

        @InjectMocks
        LangServiceImpl langService = new LangServiceImpl();

        @Mock
        LangDaoImpl langDao;

        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void getByIdTest(){
            try {
                when(langDao.findById(1).getLang()).thenReturn(COUNTRY_NAME);
                Assert.assertEquals(langService.findById(1).getLang(),COUNTRY_NAME);
            } catch (DataBaseException e) {
                LOG.error("Test not pass");
            }
        }
    }
```

so i try create mock object using this way `LangDaoImpl mock = mock(LangDaoImpl.class);` but result the same. Please help to solve the problem

Comment: Show us your test or we can't help

Comment: What is it LangServiceTest.java line 38? First I recommend doing Assert.assertNotNull(mock, "Service not initialized" ); if you fail on assertion then you know that mockito configuration is not correct

Comment: @jbarat sorry i missed

Comment: Hey. Did you tried my suggestions in my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38444479/2650174)**. *If it not helpful of you I will just remove it*.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev, Thank, your suggestion was wery good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just can assume that exception happen in this line:

```
when(langDao.findById(1).getLang()).thenReturn(COUNTRY_NAME);
```

Particularly in this place `findById(1).getLang()`.

### Solution first:

Use [`Answer#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) on `LangDaoImpl` mock creation:

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
LangDaoImpl langDao;
```

### Solution second:

Change return value to entity with expected data.

```
when(langDao.findById(1)).thenReturn(new YourEntity(COUNTRY_NAME));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your langDao.findById(1) returns null.
First mock the value it returns:

```
Xxx xxx = mock(Xxx.class); //use your own class returned by the langDao
when(langDao.finById(1)).thenReturn(xxx);
```

Also, use *@Mock LangDao* instead of *@Mock LangDaoImpl.*

Edit: one more thing: you don't have to use MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(...) if you use MockitoJUnitRunner.

Comment: thank you it's help me, but i dont understend why i should use Mock LangDao instead of Mock LangDaoImpl.

Comment: Well, Mockito is very powerful, but it has its limitations. For example, it can't override final methods of an actual class. But it has no problem implementing new behavior of an interface. That's why it's a good practice to use Mockito on interfaces (and program to interfaces in general).